# Creating a driver for a tank on a circular path

Tags: animation, drivers

I've created a driver for a tank tread using this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LovMyPoW6Ko

The driver being used is rotation X of my wheel is determined by the global Y transform of an empty, plus the rotation of the empty to account for the turning of corners.

The expression for the wheel rotation is: `var*-.5+var_001*-2`

The issue is that this does not work for following a circular path, as the world coordinate-based math keeps messing up when my tank turns the corner and returns to the beginning of its path.

Is there an expression for just "distance traveled" or something similar that I could use to animate the treads?